# Having troubles with jquery proxy

Tags: jquery

I need to do some event bindings here and there to the same function. I'll try to simplify my code as much as possible.

This is my event binding:

```
$(".preset").on("submit",$.proxy(submit_preset,this,"create"));
```

This is the function which works if I do it as annonymous  `$(".preset").on("submit",function(){ etc });` :

```
function submit_preset(e, url){
        e.preventDefault();
        var _formdata=new FormData(($(e)[0].target)); //don't mind this weird $(e)[0].target
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            data:_formdata,
            type:'post',
            success:function(datapass){
                console.log(datapass);
            }
        });
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? The function parameters or the proxy parameters? or something else?

Post-answer: the function content may have missed something, but the problem was, which I find counter-intuitive, I had to swap the parameters. Check the jsfiddle of the answer and the comments too. :)

Comment: Are you able to call this function `submit_preset` with that event binding(`$.proxy`)?

Comment: yes, I tried to alert("test") in the function, and when I submit the form, the alert pops up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the scope of the `submit_preset()` function to the `form` by using `$.proxy` therefore you need to use `this` to reference that `form` element, not `e`, as that refers to the event that was raised.

To fix your code you need to provide `this` to the `FormData()` constructor, set `contentType` and `processData` to `false` as you're sending binary data and swap the order of the parameters - the data you append to the event comes first. Try this:

```
function submit_preset(url, e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(datapass) {
      console.log(datapass);
    }
  });
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/wy1s7462/)

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer, I did include processData and contentType, I didn't put it here to make it shorter. But the **url** parameter doesn't work, because I tried to alert it, plus my action goes on the same page as a GET method.

Comment: Is `"create"` the url you're trying to call?

Comment: Ah - in that case you need to swap the order of the parameters in the function. See my updated answer

Comment: so if I have 3 parameters like: `$.proxy(submit_preset,this,url,method)` I need to invert them in my function like: `submit_preset(url, method, e)` ?